GPU Passthrough on Vostro 5490 + Ubuntu 24.04
I have followed this guide for GPU Passthrough on my Dell Vostro 5490 laptop. However, the guest (Ubuntu 22.04) cannot load the NVIDIA driver. The following error shows up on dmesg:
NVRM: GPU 0000:05:00.0: Failed to copy vbios to system memory.
NVRM: GPU 0000:05:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:1086)
NVRM: GPU 0000:05:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0

This is the output of lspci -nnk in the guest:
05:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] [10de:1d13] (rev a1)
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

On the host, the lspci -nnk shows that the GPU is using the vfio-pci driver:
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] [10de:1d13] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP108M [GeForce MX250] [1028:0959]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be?
Thank you!
